# How do I include a selector in hover text in /tellraw?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I currently have a problem with /tellraw. If I want to display a selector (@s, @p, ...) in a normal text, I always use `{"selector":"@s"}`.  But now I want to display a selector in a hover text. I have tried the following two variants, but both only showed "@s" and no player name:

```
"hoverEvent": {
            "action":"show_text",
            "value": {
                "translate":"%s executed this command.",
                "with": [{
                    "selector":"@s"
                }]
            }
        }

"hoverEvent": {
            "action":"show_text",
            "value": [{
                "selector":"@s"
            }, {
                "text":" führte diesen Befehl aus."
            }]
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in the [20w17a snapshot](https://minecraft.wiki/w/20w17a) for 1.16. The bug has been in place since 1.8, and has been present for every version up to 1.16.

Try the latest snapshot or wait for 1.16 and it should work.

Please note that the `value` component has been renamed to `contents` in 1.16.

View the bug report [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-56373).